# A complex nexted foreach that needs to repeat

Tags: php, foreach

I want to use my object to do a foreach and at the end of it create an image with a `srcset`.

Srcset should be formatted like so:

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

My output is formatted like so:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [images0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [mediaManagerOrUrl] => 0
            [mediaManagerImagesSubform] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image] => images/1600x400.jpg
                    [realSize] => 1600
                    [size] => 1200
                    [slot] => 1600
                )

        [urlImagesSubform] => stdClass Object
            (
                [url] => 
                [realSize] => 
                [size] => 
            )

    )

[images1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [mediaManagerOrUrl] => 0
        [mediaManagerImagesSubform] => stdClass Object
            (
                [image] => images/1200x400.jpg
                [realSize] => 1200
                [size] => 1000
                [slot] => 1000
            )

        [urlImagesSubform] => stdClass Object
            (
                [url] => 
                [realSize] => 
                [size] => 
            )

    )

[images2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [mediaManagerOrUrl] => 0
        [mediaManagerImagesSubform] => stdClass Object
            (
                [image] => images/800x400.jpg
                [realSize] => 800
                [size] => 800
                [slot] => 700
            )

        [urlImagesSubform] => stdClass Object
            (
                [url] => 
                [realSize] => 
                [size] => 
            )

    )

[images3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [mediaManagerOrUrl] => 0
        [mediaManagerImagesSubform] => stdClass Object
            (
                [image] => images/400x400.jpg
                [realSize] => 400
                [size] => 480
                [slot] => 400
            )

        [urlImagesSubform] => stdClass Object
            (
                [url] => 
                [realSize] => 
                [size] => 
            )

    )
```

)

Initially I started by using nested foreach statements.  However, I then realised that I actually needed to pull out all 4 images, and using nested foreaches would only allow for one at a time, it was doing all of the images part in a row for example.

Then I tried using this syntax.

```
foreach ($params->get('images') as $someImages) {
    echo '<img srcset="' . $someImages->mediaManagerImagesSubform->image . " " . $someImages->mediaManagerImagesSubform->realSize . ',"
            sizes="(max-width:' . $someImages->mediaManagerImagesSubform->size . ') ' . $someImages->mediaManagerImagesSubform->slot . ', 
            src="' . $defaultImage . '" alt="'. $altText . '">';
}
```

Which is very complicated and didn't work.  Can anyone help me to understand how to achieve this?  I am starting to think that I need to fire the data into an array somehow, thus breaking it out of the nested syntax and putting it altogether first before calling it.  Would that be more sensible?

To further complicate things I think I need to do a count so I can add in the commas but not on the last instance.

Comment: Please add some language tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final answer was using two different foreach statements and then an `$i` and then using full paths for my variables.

```
<?php 
    $i = 0;

    echo '<img srcset="';
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo $image->mediaManagerImagesSubform->image . " " . $image->mediaManagerImagesSubform->realSize . "w";
        echo ', ';
    }
    echo '" size="';
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo '(max-width: ';
        echo $image->mediaManagerImagesSubform->size . 'px) ' . $image->mediaManagerImagesSubform->slot . "px";
        echo ', ';
    }
    echo '" src="' . $defaultImage . '" alt="'. $altText . '">';
?>
```